# DS1302 RTC module running too fast

Tags: arduino-mega, rtc

I am using a DS1302 RTC module with an Arduino Mega 2560 Rev 3. I follow steps on this [website](https://surtrtech.com/2018/01/27/how-to-simply-use-ds1302-rtc-module-with-arduino-board-and-lcd-screen/) since I have no experience with RTC module before. Here are the outputs I am getting.

```
17:15:21.835 -> Current Date / Time: 26/2/2023 17:15:44
17:15:26.830 -> Current Date / Time: 26/2/2023 17:16:13
17:15:31.856 -> Current Date / Time: 26/2/2023 17:16:42
17:15:36.853 -> Current Date / Time: 26/2/2023 17:17:11
```

As you can see from the above output, the DS1302 is running five times faster than the real time (output past 30 seconds as real word past 5 seconds). Same thing happened if use different codes with different libraries.

Does this mean the RTC module itself is broken, or I can modify RTC module's speed with code?

```cpp
//This code is to use with DS1302 RTC module, it permits you to setup the actual time and date
//And you can visualize them on the serial monitor
//This code is a modified version of the code provided in virtuabotixRTC library
//Refer to https://Surtrtech.com for more information
 
#include <virtuabotixRTC.h> //Library used
 
//Wiring SCLK -> 6, I/O -> 7, CE -> 8
//Or CLK -> 6 , DAT -> 7, Reset -> 8

virtuabotixRTC myRTC(6, 7, 8); //If you change the wiring change the pins here also
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Set the current date, and time in the following format:
  // seconds, minutes, hours, day of the week, day of the month, month, year
  myRTC.setDS1302Time(15, 15, 17, 7, 26, 2, 2023); //Here you write your actual time/date as shown above 
  //but remember to "comment/remove" this function once you're done
  //The setup is done only one time and the module will continue counting it automatically
}
 
void loop() {
  // This allows for the update of variables for time or accessing the individual elements.
  myRTC.updateTime();
 
  // Start printing elements as individuals
  Serial.print("Current Date / Time: ");
  Serial.print(myRTC.dayofmonth); //You can switch between day and month if you're using American system
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(myRTC.month);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(myRTC.year);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(myRTC.hours);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(myRTC.minutes);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(myRTC.seconds);
 
  // Delay so the program doesn't print non-stop
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: There is a crystal (a metallic cylinder) on the RTC clock module. Can you please report what is written on it?

Comment: Is the backup battery installed?

Comment: The crystal is 32.768kHz and I think it has a specific load capacitance of 6 pF. The backup battery was installed and it was also connected to the 5V rail from the Arduino.

Comment: If I change `delay(5000);` to `delay(1000);`, it is still running 5 times faster.

Comment: [This electrical stack exchange answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323566/32-khz-crystal-not-operating-as-expected) covers the problems, theory of design & testing of such crystal oscillators.  It's likely more then you want to know.  These things are cheap. Less than $10 from reputable suppliers and only a few from questionable sources.  If you bought it from the likes of Adafruit, they might replace it. If I buy it from a questionable source I usually buy a few just in case one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the exact same issue today (using Arduino Uno/atmega328) and a module/board like this:
https://surtrtech.com/2018/01/27/how-to-simply-use-ds1302-rtc-module-with-arduino-board-and-lcd-screen/
When reading out time after setting it, it runs 5-6 times too fast.

I found some hint here regarding precision:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/ds1302-drift/327796/7

However, they were talking about a 2 minutes of drift every 24 hours which for sure is a totally different thing.
One comment there was to pay special attention to the ground as noise there might be interpreted as additional clock signals and speed up the clock. So I played with the grounds on the board and disconnected everything else connected so far to pins of the Arduino board, but that did not change anything, still 5-6 times faster.

I also played with and without CR2032 battery and 5V and 3.3V input to the clock board's VCC input pin and ...suddenly... it worked ok.
I think with 3.3V input on VCC and no battery, it initially had the "normal" precision but now I can again connect it to 5V input and it still runs normal...
I also kept it a while disconnected from external power source (only running on battery), then connecting it back to the Laptop and reading out date/time values and still it worked ok.

It is totally weird.

Regards, Dan